# meijer G function integration

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve one integral of two meijer G functions, and most of the papers I looked at were referring to one equation to solve such integrals .. the problem is that I've been searching for this reference for several days with no luck. So can any one provide me with equation Eq.(2.24.1.1) from the below reference:

A. Prudnikov, Y. Brychkov, and O. Marichev, Integrals and Series,Volume 3: More Special Functions. CRC, 1999.

Comment: Care to post the integral you're trying to compute?

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are looking for it is available at this link
http://functions.wolfram.com/07.34.21.0013.01